# How to reference multiple string values in array in Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to store multiple string in for loop but it giving me unwanted answer.
My code is :

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr=("ps -ef | grep icsmpgum | grep $USER | grep -v grep | awk '{print $9,$8}' | awk '{print $1}'")

for i in "${arr[@]}"    
do
   echo "$i"
done
```

The output of

```
ps -ef | grep icsmpgum | grep $USER | grep -v grep | awk '{print $9,$8}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

is :

```
icsmpgum     
ABC
DEF
```

**I want to refer to these 3 string values in for loop** but after applying for loop as mention above it giving me output as :

Output :

```
ps -ef | grep icsmpgum | grep tsaprm1 | grep -v grep | awk '{print ,}' | awk '{print }'
```

How should I store these string values in variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a command substitution, rather than quoting the command:

```
arr=( $(ps -ef | grep icsmpgum | grep $USER | grep -v grep | awk '{print $9,$8}' | awk '{print $1}') )
```

I suspect that this will work but there's a lot of further tidying up to be done; all the filtering that you want to do is possible in one call to awk:

```
arr=( $(ps -ef | awk -v user="$USER" '!/awk/ && /icsmpgum/ && $0 ~ user { print $9 }') )
```

As mentioned in the comments, there are potential risks to building an array like this (e.g. glob characters such as `*` would be expanded and you would end up with extra values in the array). A safer option would be to use a process substitution:

```
read -ra arr < <(ps -ef | awk -v user="$USER" '!/awk/ && /icsmpgum/ && $0 ~ user { print $9 }')
```

Comment: This will make the output from the command substitution undergo pathname expansion - which might not be a problem - but to be safe one could use `read -ra arr < <(ps ....)`